# Django Template Engine datetime comparison not working

Tags: django, django-templates, comparator, python-datetime, python-relativedelta

I'm trying to build a small BBS-like app in Django, and I want to be able to restrict users from deleting posts more than 30 minutes old. However, I can't get the datetime comparison to work in the template engine.

Here is a snippet of my views:

```
context = {
            ...
            "message_time" : datetime.utcnow() + relativedelta(minutes=-30) 
        }
```

And here is the django template in the html:

```
{% if request.session.userid == post.user.id and post.created_at >= message_time %}
            <form action="/wall/message/{{ post.id }}/delete" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit">Delete</button>
            </form>
            {% endif %}
```

For some reason, the delete button doesn't appear with this snippet, however it works without it (i.e. the message id/session id functionality is fine). I've tried using different combos of relativedelta +/- 30 minutes, created_at greater/less than message_time, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone reading this, I figured out the issue:

datetime.utcnow() is timezone naive (despite the name). Therefore, at some point when the template was rendering, the message time "reset" to midnight UTC (I can't fully explain why, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777753/converting-datetime-date-to-utc-timestamp-in-python) is what clued me in).

Using datetime.now(timezone.utc) allowed me to pass the datetime as aware and UTC, which stopped the issue from happening.